# classification report in keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

i am using the classification report to calculate the precision, recall and fscore for the following model

```python
x_train = train[:,[3,4,5,6,7]]
x_test = test[:,[3,4,5,6,7]]
y_train = train[:,8]
y_test = test[:,8]

n = x_train.shape[0]
n2 = x_test.shape[0]
L = 32
X_train_seq = []
Y_train_seq = []
for k in range(n - L + 1):
    X_train_seq.append(x_train[k : k + L])
    Y_train_seq.append(y_train[k : k + L])

X_test_seq = []
Y_test_seq = []
for k1 in range(n2 - L + 1):
    X_test_seq.append(x_test[k1 : k1 + L])
    Y_test_seq.append(y_test[k1 : k1 + L])

X_train_seq = np.array(X_train_seq)
Y_train_seq = np.array(Y_train_seq)
X_test_seq = np.array(X_test_seq)
Y_test_seq = np.array(Y_test_seq)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(32, 5), activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='sigmoid' ))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(X_train_seq, Y_train_seq, batch_size = 200, epochs = 15,
                 verbose = 2)
avg = np.mean(hist.history['acc'])
print('The Average Training Accuracy is', avg)
score=model.evaluate(X_test_seq, Y_test_seq, batch_size=200,verbose=2)
print(score)

y_pred=model.predict(X_test_seq, batch_size=200, verbose=2)
report = classification_report(Y_test_seq, y_pred.round())
print(report)
```

the problem here is the output, it is not true i guess and i don't know why !
this is a sample of the output

```python
 precision    recall  f1-score   support

0       0.35      0.11      0.17     30146
1       0.35      0.12      0.17     30146
2       0.35      0.12      0.17     30146
3       0.35      0.12      0.18     30146
4       0.35      0.12      0.18     30146
5       0.35      0.12      0.18     30146
```

why the values are very low, although the accuracy is 94%

Answer (score 0):

You can not rely just on Accuracy as your metric. Its a poor metric to evaluate your model. Usually EM and F scores are complete and more descriptive measure of your actual model performance.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is a significant imbalance across predicted classess so your model has learned to predict really well the majority class but fails on the minority clasess hence the high accuracy and low recall, precision, etc.